# Microsoft Release Management timeout during deploy step

Tags: ms-release-management

We're using Microsoft's Release Management to deploy our web application to our test environment (QA). It is a straight-forward MVC.Net web application. Our build generates a web deploy package and we have a command script that sets some parameters based on the target environment (QA is just the first step), and then runs the standard Web Deploy command line tool. The command script works without errors when run from the command line outside of Release Management.

When we move this process into Release Management using the command-line tool, we encounter a timeout during the deploy step of the workflow. The error is:

```
The installation command \"powershell -command ./RunCommandLine.ps1 -FilePath 'Deployment\Deploy.cmd' -Arguments '/T:QA /E:intranet' -UserDomain 'domain' -UserName 'username' -UserPassword '*****'\" reached the configured timeout (2 minutes); the process was terminated.
```

We've checked the output log and there is no information from the script at all. We have echo commands in the beginning that should at least dump some output to the log before any action is taken.

The interesting thing is that when we click the "Retry failed deployment" button, the retry succeeds in about 15 seconds without any issues. This happens for each release - fails with timeout, retry succeeds in 15 seconds.

Any ideas from any release management gurus is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In release management , what deployment steps have you chosen ?  i am assuming a powershell command ? can we do it using a xcopy ( works for me). Also i would request you do follow this  blog on debugging the release mangement agent. opening the agent in debug mode has solved my problems or atleast told me about my problem most of the times. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/12/13/how-to-enable-detailed-logs-and-collect-traces-from-various-release-management-components.aspx